# ¿Error al hacer una carga masiva (LOAD FILE) con PDO MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

tengo un fichero .SQL que contiene la siguiente línea:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'mi.csv' 
INTO TABLE myTable 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' 
ENCLOSED BY '"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' 
IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

Pero me da el siguiente error:

> Error: PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access
> violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
> that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax
> to use near ''' at line 1 in C:\miPHP.php:3

Si quito `FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'` me da este otro error:

> Error: PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access
> violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
> that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax
> to use near 'ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' IGNORE 1
> LINES' at line 1 in C:\miPHP.php:3

`C:\miPHP.php:3` es `prepare`:

```
                        $stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
                        $stmt->execute();
```

Comment: ¿Y qué hay en la línea  `1` del archivo `miPHP.php`? Puede que el error esté en la forma de escribir la cadena de la consulta en PHP. Muestra ese código pulsando en [edit].

Comment: Lo que falla es "prepare". He editado la pregunta tal y como lo has pedido

Comment: El problema parecen ser las comillas simples, porque la query que intenta "preparar" es: Preparando query: LOAD DATA INFILE 'micsv.csv' INTO TABLE mytable FIELDS TERMINATED BY '

Comment: Pero indica cómo creas `$query` en tu código.

Comment: Se lee línea por línea del fichero micsv.csv. En la pregunta he puesto una línea exacta de cómo se encuentra en este fichero.

Comment: Tenemos que ver lo que hay en `$query`. Pon un `var_dump($query);` y dinos qué muestra.

Comment: string(102) "LOAD DATA INFILE 'micsv.csv' INTO TABLE mytable FIELDS TERMINATED BY '" definitivamente, no está cogiendo todo del csv

Comment: $queries = explode(';', file_get_contents($sqlFile)); aquí está el problema.. ¿Cómo hago que no tenga en cuenta el ';' pero sí el ; final?

Comment: Le he puesto un [FIN] o similar para luego hacer el explode('[FIN]', ...);

Comment: Pon un `var_dump(file_get_contents($sqlFile));` y agrega la salida de eso en la pregunta. No somos adivinos, debes mostrar con lo que estás trabajando en realidad, no con lo que piensas que debería ser. Además, pon siempre el contexto donde se crean los datos. Aquí puede haber un error en el mismo contenido, o en la forma de hacer el `explode`. Nada de eso está en la pregunta original, vas dando la información a cuenta gotas, y eso no agiliza la resolución del problema.